# Compile C++ class with a header file to use it in python?

Tags: python, c++, compilation, g++, shared-objects

I have a `my_class.h`:

```cpp
// my_class.h

namespace N
{
    class my_class
    {
    public:
        void hello_world();
    };
}
```

with a `my_class.cpp` file.

```cpp
// my_class.cpp

extern "C" {
    #include "my_class.h"
}
#include <iostream>

using namespace N;
using namespace std;

void my_class::hello_world()
{
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
}
```

I want to create a shared object `my_class.so` file to use it in python.
Therefore, I am using the `g++` compiler.

```sh
g++ -fPIC -shared -o my_class.so my_class.cpp
```

Using the shared object in python `my_class.so`

```py
import ctypes

my_class = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./my_class.so')
my_class.hello_world
```

I get the following error message:

```sh
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
./my_class.so: undefined symbol: hello_world
```

I do not know how to interpret this.
Note:

- `my_class.hello_world()` results the same error

Comment: Why are you including a c++ header inside extern C? You are using C linkage with C++ code, so it wont work

Comment: Do you mean that I need to remove the `extern "C"` wrapper in `my_class.cpp`?
It is still not working even without it.

Comment: I do not know how python handles mangled names. However, extern C definitely shouldn’t be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much to talk about, but I'll try to be brief:

1. extern "C" is going to make those symbols available in the C-syntax.
   (You do want this)
2. C-syntax does not support classes or namespaces.
3. the python dynamic library loader is grabbing ALL the symbols - not
   just your class. (It seems there is some confusion there with the naming scheme)

To Fix: Simply eliminate your class and namespaces (or add a C-API pass-through).

**my_class.h**

```
extern "C" {
   void hello_world();
}
```

**my_class.cpp**

```
#include "my_class.h"
#include <iostream>

void hello_world()
{
        std::cout<<"Hello, World" << std::endl;
}
```

After you build, use nm or objdump to verify that the symbol hello_world is defined and not mangled. Example:

```
>> nm my_class.so | grep hello
0000000000000935 T hello_world
```

And your python code will need an open close parenthesis to tell it to execute the function:

```
import ctypes

my_class = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./my_class.so')
my_class.hello_world()
```

Comment: Thank you! But I did not get the usage of `extern "C" {...}` in this context. Why do I need it in the header file and why do I need it at all?

Comment: If it worked without the extern "C", then the python package ctypes might be smart enough to search for the mangled version as well. 
C++ mangles it's symbols, C does not. For example, run nm on a binary with a hello_world() function compiled as cpp. You should see something like "_Z11hello_worldv". This is the actual name written to the binary file for future lookups. to ensure the mangling doesn't happen, you can use 'extern "C"'.